# Remove grid columns control component

Tags: magento2

I would like to remove the default columns control component in product_listing.xml, I tried with this code but it's not working :

```
 <columnsControls name="columns_controls">
     <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
         <item name="remove" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
     </argument>
 </columnsControls>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `visible` attribute has no effect for the `columnControls` component, but you can use a "hacky" way which affects the `render` function:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </columnsControls>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

#### Exploration:

The `columnControls` component (`magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/grid/controls/columns.js`) added to the `listingToolbar` component, which have a default template `magento/module-ui/view/base/web/templates/grid/toolbar.html` where the `dataGridActions` region should be rendered during a listing loading process. Our `columnControls` component assigned to that region by default in the own code:

```
defaults: {
    template: 'ui/grid/controls/columns',
        // ...
        viewportSize: 18,
        displayArea: 'dataGridActions', // <<< Here it is 
        columnsProvider: 'ns = ${ $.ns }, componentType = columns',
        // ...
    },
    // ...
},
```

So, if we change the `displayArea` to the *nothing* it will not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

U can just comment this lines :

```
 <columnsControls name="columns_controls">
     <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
         <item name="remove" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
     </argument>
 </columnsControls>
```

Or just remove them.